# Php bindParam error

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting a error on my server on my MAMP server it worked but on my live server there is an error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

How to fix this? and what is wrong or why?

My code:

```
try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO collection (name, numberO, city) VALUES (:name, :numberO, :city)";
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $sth = $statement->execute( ['name' => $name, 'numberO' => $number, 'city' => $city] );
} catch(PDOExepction $e) {
    echo "SORRY";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You're on an older PHP version that doesn't support the `[]` array shortcut notation. Use `->execute(array(....))` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$sth = $statement->execute(array(
    ':name' => $name, 
    ':numberO' => $number, 
    ':city' => $city
));
```

As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].
[More about PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

Check your server's php version.

You need  **PHP 5.4+** to use shorthand arrays

asp per [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

1) Update php version or
2) Change short hand array syntax

Comment: The server version is: 5.3.28